# Data not getting to RESTful function

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jersey-2.0

I have a REST function that I am trying to get working. It doesn't do much because I am just trying to get it to work:

```
@POST
@Path("/saveword/")
public void addNewWord(String theInput)
{
  System.out.println("Word info received.");
}
```

That is the server side code. On the client side, I am using some Javascript in conjunction with the HTML:

```
      <button type="button" name="CreateNewWord" onclick="addWord()">Create Word</button>
```

The Javascript is below:

```
   function addWord()
   {
   var word = {
     "fname": wordfrm.formname.value,
     "descrip": wordfrm.description.value,
     "position": wordfrm.position.value
   };   

   $.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost:8080/SaveDemo/rest/savedb/saveword",
       type: "POST",
       data: word
   }).done(function( e ) {
        alert( "word was saved" + e );
   });

   }
```

I think I am doing everything right, but the RESTful function, for some reason, is not being called. Evidently, there is something wrong, either in the function definition or in the Javascript. I am not getting any error messages or failures, but the addWord() method is not being called.

Am I missing something? Can anyone see what is issing or wrong?

Someone please advise...

Comment: On the server side is there infrastructure that hooks the `/SaveDemo/rest/savedb/saveword` route up to your `addNewWord()` function?

Comment: I copied your js function and button to a new html document, and addWord() method actually _is_ called. You can `console.log` smth from it to make sure for yourself. Also, open `Network` tab in browser developer tools and check whether your POST request is sent.

Comment: I checked the network. The POST was being sent but I was getting a 404 error. I soon discovered that there was a typo in the URL. This is somewhat embarrassing and I apologize for wasting people's time...